# FreeForm Pro Composer require field

Tags: solspace-freeform

How do I make a field require with the new composer? in the past I would create the form and include:

`{exp:freeform:form require_captcha=“yes” required="name|email"}` (which still work on the site).

With the new composer forms I try to do it the same way and I am not getting an indication to required fields.

`{exp:freeform:composer form_name="contact-form" composer_template_name="general_template"  required="name|email" require_captcha=“yes”}`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When you are building composer forms, in the bottom left hand corner of each field is a widget where you can toggle required:

[image: require_field]

It also seems that you are forcing a composer template, you can do that in the upper left hand corner of composer:

[image: composer template choose]

Unless you need specific overrides, the composer tag was designed to only really need to have the form name or id:

```
{exp:freeform:composer form_name="contact-form"}
```

Thats not to say what you are doing with the tag is *wrong* just more work than you have to be doing.