# How to make a Freeform text field required

Tags: solspace-freeform

I must be missing something, but I can't figure out how to make a text field required using Freeform Pro. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

A quick sweep of them 'ol documentation thingies gives you the answer.

https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#required

Use the required parameter when outputting your form.

```
{exp:freeform:form
    form_name="contact_form"
    required="name|email"}

    Form stuff goes here.

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

**Edit** If you are using the Composer tool, see this answer:

[FreeForm Pro Composer require field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15183/freeform-pro-composer-require-field)